# Parse specific string from variable HTML result

Tags: javascript, string, google-apps-script, match

I'm running a script that returns HTML in the following format into a variable (i.e var results;)

```
var results = titleResults[0];
return results;

***RETURNS the below***
<h2>
<a href="https://www.southwest.com/about/southwest/index.html"><b>About Southwest</b></a>
</h2>
```

How can I parse out only the 'southwest.com' into another variable?

Comment: do you mean ' https://www.southwest.com/about/southwest/index.html' or only 'southwest.com'

Comment: Is this executed on server with apps script or javascript on browser?

Comment: I assume this isn't always going to be "soutewest.com", it could be some other site. Will it always have the `www.` prefix? What can you actually count on being there? e.g. 1) always an anchor, 2) always wrapped in an h2, 3)...?

Comment: I want to return 'domain.com' only as the result. It will not always be southwest, it will depend on what my search criteria is. This is executed on Google Scripts App.

Comment: @BigMike I understand you want only "southwest.com" as the new variable; I'm asking what the href you receive in `results` _might_ look like. It's not always going to be "www.southwest.com" so - will whatever you get in `results` _**always**_ have `www.` before the domain name? @cнŝdk otherwise excellent answer assume there will be a "www" prefix. Will it always be like that, such as "www.united.com", or could it be "travel.united.com" or "air.travel.united.com"? All answers so far would fail on `air.travel.united.com`

Comment: @StephenP - The results variable looks like this for southwest.com: 

    <h2 class=""result__title"">
    <a rel=""nofollow"" class=""result__a"" href=""/l/?kh=-1&amp;uddg=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.southwest.com%2Fhtml%2Fabout%2Dsouthwest%2Findex.html"">About <b>Southwest</b> - <b>Southwest</b> <b>Airlines</b></a>
     </h2>

Comment: @BigMike I understand it looks like that for your _southwest.com_ **example** — will it look like that, with the `www.` prefix, for _every possible airline_ that you might receive in `results`? I mean, if you're only trying to solve it for the example results you're showing then the answer is `const domain = 'southwest.com';`  If you get _some other airline_ as results will it have the `www.` prefix? Is that guaranteed? Do you have any guarantees about what the domain + path will look like? cнŝdk has the best answer so far, but it will fail if there is not a "www." in "www.someairline.com"

Comment: @StephenP With my Edit, it won't fail anymore if there's no `www`,  I have updated the [`regex`](https://regex101.com/r/COrZmt/4) now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var results = `<h2>
<a href="https://www.southwest.com/about/southwest/index.html"><b>About Southwest</b></a>
</h2>`


//Getting southwest.com :

let southwest = results.split("www.")[1].split("/")[0]
//this method works for all urls,
let example = "http://www.example.com/index.html".split("www.")[1].split("/")[0]

console.log(southwest,"\n",example)
```

Comment: `document.getElementById("h2")` will fail because the `h2` and `a` are  not part of the `document` — OP's "results" is just a text string.

Comment: Got it working: let domain = results.split("www.")[1].split("%2F")[0];
  console.log(domain);
  
  return domain;

Answer (score 2):

[EDIT] Full apps script code here:

```
  var html = '<h2><a href="https://www.southwest.com/about/southwest/index.html"><b>About Southwest</b></a></h2>';
  var doc = XmlService.parse(html);
  var root = doc.getRootElement();
  var children = root.getDescendants(); 
  children.forEach(function(ch){
    var chelm = ch.asElement();
    if(chelm && chelm.getAttribute('href'))
    {
      var href = chelm.getAttribute('href');
      var url = href.getValue();
      Logger.log(url);

      var hostname;
      if (url.indexOf("//") > -1)
          hostname = url.split('/')[2];
      else
          hostname = url.split('/')[0];
      hostname = hostname.split('://').pop();   
      hostname = hostname.split('www.').pop();
      hostname = hostname.split('?')[0];
      Logger.log(hostname);
    }
  });
```

You can use XmlService.parse in apps script and get the link node & href attribute:
https://sites.google.com/site/scriptsexamples/learn-by-example/parsing-html

From the href attribute, you can extract the domain:

```
var hostname;
if (url.indexOf("//") > -1)
    hostname = url.split('/')[2];
else
    hostname = url.split('/')[0];

hostname = hostname.split('://').pop();
hostname = hostname.split('www.').pop();
hostname = hostname.split('?')[0];
```

Comment: Thanks - how do I print the hostname (domain.com)?

Comment: @BigMike Logger.log(hostname) should print the hostname in the apps script logs (Apps script Editor Menu > View > Logs). Or, you can use FormApp.getUi().alert(hostname) to see it (replace FormApp with SpreadsheetApp or relevant Gsuite app).

Comment: This is working well, thanks. However, the actual HTMl results look more like this and it seems to break your code: "<h2 class=""result__title"">
          
            <a rel=""nofollow"" class=""result__a"" href=""/l/?kh=-1&amp;uddg=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.aa.com%2F""><b>American</b> <b>Airlines</b> - <b>Airline</b> tickets and cheap flights at AA.com</a>
          
          </h2>"

Comment: @BigMike Your HTML double quotes are formatted incorrectly (repeated twice). You are probably copy/pasting it from Google Sheets. Please fix the HTML or use single quotes:
var html = "<h2 class='result__title'> <a rel='nofollow' class='result__a' href='http://www.aa.com/'><b>American</b> <b>Airlines</b> - <b>Airline</b> tickets and cheap flights at AA.com</a> </h2>";

Comment: I put your code into a parseHTML() function. It returns: /l/?kh=-1&uddg=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.aa.com%2F for Logger.log(url)

Comment: This is an encoding problem with the html. Please provide details about how you are fetching the HTML.

Comment: I fixed it with  let domain = results.split("www.")[1].split("/")[0];

Comment: Treating HTML as string is risky. This will fail if href is "www.aa.com" instead of "www.aa.com/"

Comment: I can try your code above....I am getting some errors for domains that don't have www.

Comment: Because your HTML encoding is incorrect - https%3A%2F%2Fwww.aa.com%2F . Anyway your choice.

Comment: @BigMike You are right. My code would return http:/ along with domain, if it didnt have www. Fixed it now.

Comment: the HTML response looks more like this and your new code doesn't return anything: "<h2 class="result__title">
          
            <a rel="nofollow" class="result__a" href="/l/?kh=-1&amp;uddg=https://www.aa.com/"><b>American</b> <b>Airlines</b> - <b>Airline</b> tickets and cheap flights at AA.com</a>
          
          </h2>

Comment: @BigMike The HTML in the question is different from the HTML you have pasted here. You need the hostname of the url in query string *uddg*. Post this HTML as a different question and provide the link here. I will try to answer.

Answer (score 1):

I am not really sure if this will do it for a google app script, but **using Javascript you can extract what you need like this**:

1. You can use this `result` string as a `innerHTML` of a new HTML
   element.
2. Then extract the `href` attribute value from the `a` element.
3. And finally use a **[regex](https://regex101.com/r/COrZmt/4)** like [`\/\/(www\.)?([\w\.]+)\/?`](https://regex101.com/r/COrZmt/4) and **`.match()` method** to extract the desired output.

This is how should be your code:

```
var div = document.createElement("div");
div.innerHTML= result;
let href = div.getElementsByTagName("a")[0].href;
console.log(href.match(/\/\/(www\.)?([\w\.]+)\/?/)[1]);
```

**Demo:**

```js
let result = `<h2>
<a href="https://www.southwest.com/about/southwest/index.html"><b>About Southwest</b></a>
</h2>`;
var div = document.createElement("div");
div.innerHTML= result;
let href = div.getElementsByTagName("a")[0].href;
console.log(href.match(/\/\/(www\.)?([\w\.]+)\/?/)[2]);
```

**References:**

- [**Document.createElement()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement).
- [**Element.getElementsByTagName()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName).
- [**String.prototype.match()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match).

Comment: Mine was using `let href = div.querySelector('a').href;` but I was working to solve the issue of "what if it's not a _www_ prefix"

Comment: @StephenP Yes parsing it can be done in many ways, but we need to find the appropriate regex, I've updated my regex like this `\/\/(www\.)?([\w\.]+)\/?`, no it shoud work with any url.

Comment: I also looked at creating a URL object, like `let host = new URL(anchor.href).host` to reduce the problem space to only the host string without the protocol or path. Anyway, a definite `+1`

Comment: Yes a good idea too (y), but as I said I think the right regex is the big deal :)

Comment: @cнŝdk - Will this code work in Google Scripts app?

Comment: @BigMike well I don't have any experience with it, but normally it should work as it's based on JS, otherwise you can juste use another option to parse the `href`item, then use my `regex`to extract your desired output :)

Answer (score 0):

create a function

```js
const extractDomain = url =>
{
    let domain

    domain = url.split('/')[url.indexOf("://") > -1 ? 2 : 0]

    if (domain.indexOf("www.") > -1)
        domain = domain.split('www.')[1]

    domain = domain.split(':')[0];
    domain = domain.split('?')[0];

    return domain
}
```

```html
<h2>
    <a href="https://www.southwest.com/about/southwest/index.html" id="url"><b>About Southwest</b></a>
</h2>
```

```js
const {href} = document.getElementById('url')

const anotherVariable = extractDomain(href)
```

now anotherVariable is **"southwest.com"**

DEMO: https://jsfiddle.net/cs6bzgfn/

Comment: There is no `id="url"` in OP's _results_ variable; you can't count on that to identify the element, and the whole thing is just a text string, it's not part of the document so `document.getElementByAnything` will fail.